# Ruby on Rails, Gmaps4rails v 2.1.0 handler.addMakers(items,options) how do I put on options for dragging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, draggable, gmaps4rails, marker

After facing the

> undefined method gmaps at the line

with the code line :

```
 <%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json, "options" => { "draggable" => true  } } ) %>
```

That does not seem to work in Gmaps4rails 2.1.0

[Detailed problem and answer for it in here.](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/issues/430)

What I am asking in here is , provided the answer in the previous link, for me to be able to make the marker draggable, how should I write this method ?

1 : `handler.addMarker(<%= raw @hash.to_json %>,<% {draggable => :true }%>)`

or

2 : `handler.addMarker(<%= raw @hash.to_json %>,<% "draggable" => true }%>)`

or

What?

It just seems to not work, and the map does not load, also I'd like to know where to put it in the code,

```
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
// here ?
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  // or Here ?markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @hash.to_json %>,<%"draggable" => true %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

**Update #1 :** *Solved*

I found the answer on github, it requires a bit of time reading through the doc, but hey , It's worth taking a look at , in the end, it is exactly the answer to this question.

[Answer](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/issues/430)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass google options as a second argument:

```
handler.addMarkers([
 { 
   lat: 0,lng: 0,
   picture: {
     url: "/logo.png",
     width:  36,
     height: 36
   },
   infowindow: "hello!"
  },
 ]
 {
   draggable: true
 }
);
```

doc here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Js-Methods